# Open File From Text Box Without Reloading Page

Tags: java, jquery, html

What I've had in the past is some java that creates an array of servers on our network. On an intranet page the user would login and then start typing into a textbox which uses the java and array to give a list of valid sites as they type. They would then select the server they want (or finish typing) and click the "Start RDP" button which would post the form to the same page (gets checked for validity) and starts a download of a .rdp file for them to run which obviously starts mstsc.exe. Now I was wondering if it's possible to use jquery or something to dynamically run a perl script to check the form has a valid request and then start the download (for running by the user) of the RDP file from a link like \\someserver\somehiddenshare$\servername.rdp. The form I'm using is as follows however I appreciate this would change:

```
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../js/actb.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../js/common.js"></script>
  <script>
    var sitearray=new Array('server1','20.20.20.20','server2','20.20.20.21','server3','20.20.20.22');
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
<!-- OTHER CONTENT IN HERE -->
  <form action="same_page.pl" method="post" name="rdp_start">
  <input type="hidden" value="start_rdp">
  <input type="text" size="25" name="start_rdp" id="srv" class="GreyLB8">
  <input type="submit" value="Start RDP">
  <script>
   var obj = actb(document.getElementById('srv'),sitearray);
  </script>
  </form>
<!-- OTHER CONTENT IN HERE -->
 </body>
</html>
```

Obviously the page has much more content and it's that content I don't want to change as the user might be in the middle of updating another form but will need to check a server first. Currently opening the RDP requires the page to basically be reloaded.

Thanks in advance for any advice. E.

Answer (score 0):

You just change the action attribute of your form tag to point to rdp file. Dynamically via javaScript and add target="_new", so it is send to a new tab which is closed as soon the browser recognizes it's a download.